# How to use td-agent-bit to output log files as messages？

Tags: td-agent

How to use td-agent-bit to output log files as messages, either on a per-line basis or for lines that start with "HH:mm:ss," and send them downstream, instead of outputting multiple lines of logs together each time?
logs：

```html
15:42:43 [cmd:local,tid:xxx]
15:42:43 [tid:xxx]
```

I want messages like below:

```html
{
    "message":" 15:42:43 [cmd:local,tid:xxx]",
    "type":"test-log",
    "@version":"1",
    "port":31426,
    "@timestamp":"2023-09-08T10:59:45.806Z",
    "host":"172.31.48.61"
}

{
    "message":" 15:42:43 [tid:xxx]    ",
    "type":"test-log",
    "@version":"1",
    "port":31426,
    "@timestamp":"2023-09-08T10:59:45.806Z",
    "host":"172.31.48.61"
}
```

not:

```html
{
    "message":" 15:42:43 [cmd:local,tid:xxx] 15:42:43 [tid:xxx]",
    "type":"test-log",
    "@version":"1",
    "port":31426,
    "@timestamp":"2023-09-08T10:59:45.806Z",
    "host":"172.31.48.61"
}
```